# JSON.NET Deserializing from file

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, monogame

I'm trying to deserialize an array from a file. I keep getting the error "cannot deserialize JSON object into array" because it is apparently not in the correct format. However, I copied the JSON into a string and used it within the C# class and everything works fine. When I went back to getting it from the file, same error as before. I have no idea what the issue is!

The in-class JSON string:

```
string json = @"[{
                'id': 1,
                'name': '...',
                'image': '...',
                'attack': 12,
                'defense': 3,
                'magic': 4,
                'speed': 2,
                'hp': 20
            },
            {   
                'id': 2,
                'name': '...',
                'image': '...',
                'attack': 3,
                'defense': 14,
                'magic': 9,
                'speed': 7,
                'hp': 14


            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'name': '...',
                'image': '...',
                'attack': 3,
                'defense': 14,
                'magic': 9,
                'speed': 7,
                'hp': 14
            }

            ]";

monsters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Monster>>(json);
```

And the file:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': '...',
        'image': '...',
        'attack': 12,
        'defense': 3,
        'magic': 4,
        'speed': 2,
        'hp': 20
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': '...',
        'image': '...',
        'attack': 15,
        'defense': 5,
        'magic': 3,
        'speed': 4,
        'hp': 17
    }
]


monsters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Monster>>(File.ReadAllText(@"Content\Data\monsterData.json"));
```

monsters is defined as List above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file contains fewer objects than the in-class string just because I was testing something else

Comment: Do me a favor, leave the json in a string, but also read from the file the same way. Compare the strings using string.Equals. Are they /actually/ the same?

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes in your JSON file to double quotes, try any online JSON validator, I use this one [JSONFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

Comment: The formatter says it's all okay with the double quotes, but I'm getting the same error still

Comment: Alright, so even when I've copied from the string to the file, it says the strings are different soo gotta figure that out...

Comment: Try writing your good JSON string to a different file.  Then use a diff tool to compare the files to see what is different.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share the "Monster" class because I am doing the same thing and every thing is working fine.
Below mentioned is my code

```
public class Monster
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int attack { get; set; }
    public int defense { get; set; }
    public int magic { get; set; }
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public int hp { get; set; }
}
```

Following code read from Json file and deserialize it

```
   var data = File.ReadAllText(@"xyz\json1.json");
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Monster>>(data);
```

Following is the JsonFile:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "...",
      "image": "...",
      "attack": 12,
      "defense": 3,
      "magic": 4,
      "speed": 2,
      "hp": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "...",
      "image": "...",
      "attack": 15,
      "defense": 5,
      "magic": 3,
      "speed": 4,
      "hp": 17
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Json with single quotes is invalid. Try to replace the single quotes with double and use List class, since your json is an array

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"xyz\json1.json");

var json=text.Replace("'","\"");
     
List<Monster> monsters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Monster>>(json);
```